# How to forward IP:PORT with cloudflare?

Tags: dns, cloudflare

I have a website that has to be forwarded with the IP and Port IP:Port but I can not find a way to do that in cloudflare every post I tried it gave me an "Invalid Target" error I tried page rules it didn't work and with different types of DNS like CNAME, AAAA and A still the same error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to specify port and for a mask use an origin rule!